# The select box dynamic add option not working in firefox3.6

Tags: javascript, html

I am having the below code for population the select box dynamically.THis works fine in all browsers except FireFox 3.6

```
var option25 = document.createElement("option");
option25.text = '25 miles';
option25.value = 25;
if(rad == '25')
{
    option25.selected = 'selected';
}
var combo = document.getElementById('ddlProximity_' + controlId);
combo.add(option25); //not working in FF3.6
```

Any suggestions

Comment: I don't believe you tried every web browser in existence.  What goes wrong in Firefox 3.6?

Comment: Its working fine in IE ,FF 15 ,Chrome .. I know what browsers i am supporting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming combo is a select menu, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Cbtx/2/) example.

```
if (typeof combo.add === 'function') {
    combo.add(option25);
} else if (typeof combo.appendChild === 'function') {
    combo.appendChild(option25);
}
```

​

Comment: This looks like the exact same code as the one the OP posted.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, no, this uses appendChild, which ought to work, but probably doesn't in IE.

Comment: The link was updated to fallback to use appendChild if select.add is not available.

Comment: @krg the if-else part of fiddle is not working in FF3.6.But combo.appendChild(option25); this code works in FF3 3.6 but not in IE

Comment: if ( ($.browser.safari) && ($.browser.version == '3.6') ){
759 i am using this above code to differenciate between the browsers.Its working fine now.Thanks

Comment: Nice! Now I can kill my VM ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `add` method on select elements takes two arguments in Gecko versions older than 7 ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement#add%28%29)).

In IE it only takes one argument, or two if it's IE 8 in IE 8 standards mode, or something [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If we take krg's code and check the arity before calling `add` it works in Firefox 3.6.28, Firefox 15.0.1, and IE 9:

```
if (typeof combo.add === 'function') {
    if (combo.add.arity === 1) {
        combo.add(option25);
    } else {
        combo.add(option25, null);
    }
} else if (typeof combo.appendChild === 'function') {
    combo.appendChild(option25);
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to ensure that your JS code works across a wide spectrum of browsers, I would use a JavaScript framework such as jQuery to perform the DOM manipulation. JS frameworks have worked out most of the cross-browser problems and abstracted away the handling of them, so that you don't have to worry about writing code to address problems in a specific browser. Here's jQuery's site: http://jquery.com/.

Now to accomplish what your example says in jQuery, you would do the following:

```
var option25 = $('<option>').val(25).text('25 miles');
if (rad == '25') {
    option25.attr('selected', 'selected');
}

var combo = $('#ddlProximity_' + controlId);
combo.append(option25); // Will work in all browsers supported by jQuery
```

If you really want to do this without any JS frameworks, I would take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp . The add method should work, but there are some caveats in IE versions prior to 8 and your page must have a proper DOCTYPE declaration. You can also try appendChild, but I would test it in a few browsers to see if that accomplishes what you need.

Comment: Looks like that ticket is for jQuery 1.2. Is that still an issue in jQuery 1.8?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It says they won't fix it though, so I'd assume that means it's not fixed.

Comment: @DaniF thanks for the suggestion. This code was done by someone else and im fixing this issue.That person used Javascript in the whole page,now its too late to change to JQuery. But i love to do in Jquery...